# How to import the png image to the node-red-contrib-web-worlmap

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-red

I have some issue, and maybe someone had the same.
I have published the "points" on the map, as in the picture:
[image: web world map example]

At this moment, I am trying to upload the PNG file over this place(floor plan).
I have tried this:
[image: node-red]

```
var imageBounds = [[90.59947103975521,25.315620183944702],[90.59961064446937,25.315349280834196],[90.5997008765643,25.31547199189663],[90.59956510273313,25.315744236111641]];
msg.payload= { map : {
    overlay:"test",
    url:'http://example.jpg',
    bounds: imageBounds

}};
return msg;
```

but I have no output. Is it possible? or maybe I am doing something wrong.
Please help.

What I have done next:
change the imageBounds variable to :

```
var imageBounds = [[90.59947103975521,25.315620183944702],[90.5997008765643,25.31547199189663]];
```

and the result is:
[image: new issue]
but must be:
[image: must be!!]

Any ideas?????

Comment: Please don't post images of code, it makes them impossible to search for.

Comment: @hardillb , sorry, I have changed.

Comment: You might need to add an `opts` to the `map` object

Comment: @hardillb, I have used: opt:{ opacity:1.0, attribution:"&copy; company" }. But does not work

Answer (score 0):

You need to pre-rotate (and add a transparent background) your input image.

As image overlays only take the top left and bottom right corner of a rectangular image and expect the top edge to point north.